# Is there a way to visualize the flag on a second monitor while in loupe view on Adobe Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, monitors

When I'm culling my pictures I like to put my laptop on grid view and put the images on display on a 50" inches TV on my wall. One problem I have when doing this is that when I go back and forth while reviewing the pictures, I have to go back to the small scree of my laptop to see if I've already flagged that picture or not. Is there a way to see the flag on the second screen? When I use "i" as shortcut I can only see the info about the metadata.